# How to use AD dialog "Select User or Group" in a Windows Forms application?

Tags: .net, winforms, active-directory

I am searching how to use AD dialog like it is in SSMS:

SSMS ->Security->Users->New
Database User
[b]Select User or Group[/b]

How to call dialog like this in a WinForms app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the "Directory Object Picker". The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/directory-object-picker) is all about native code, not .NET. But someone did write a .NET library for it: [Active Directory Object Picker](https://github.com/Tulpep/Active-Directory-Object-Picker).